# Составил код, но не могу вывести числа. Числа в обратном порядке

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Мой код разбивает число. Например введём число 450, он должен вывести 4 5 0, но выводит 0 5 4. Код считает всё верно, но выводит цифры не в правильном порядке. Что нужно записать в Print???

```
a=input()
b=len(a)
a=int(a)
c=a
d=a
for i in range(b):
    c=d%10
    print(c, end=' ')
    d=d//10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сохраняйте цифры в массив и возвращайте массив в реверсивном виде (задом наперёд)

Пример:

```
def digitalize(num):
    num = abs(num)
    res = []
    while num > 0:
        res.append(num % 10)
        num = num // 10
    return list(reversed(res))

In [4]: digitalize(12345)
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [5]: digitalize(450)
Out[5]: [4, 5, 0]
```